# Weakening or strengthening theorems in A Logical Approach to Discrete Math by Gries and Schneider

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In *A Logical Approach to Discrete Math* by Gries and Schneider I find the part below (pp. 57-58) rather confusing:

> Each of the theorems (3.76a)-(3.76e) is called weakening or strengthening, depending on whether it is used to transform the antecedent **into** the consequent, thus weakening it, or to
> transform the consequent **into** the antecedent, thus strengthening it.

What do "to transform the antecedent into the consequent" and "to transform the consequent into the antecedent" mean? My understanding is weakening and strengthening modifies (=transforms) the antecedent and/or the consequent. Why do the authors put it as the antecedent and consequent are **transformed one into the other**.

$$\begin{align*}
\text{(3.76) Weakening/strengthening:}\ &(a)\ p \Rightarrow p \lor q\\[5pt]
&\text{(b)}\ p \land q \Rightarrow p \\[5pt]
&\text{(c)}\ p\land q \Rightarrow p \lor q\\[5pt]
&\text{(d)}\ p \lor (q \land r) \Rightarrow p \lor q\\[5pt]
&\text{(e)}\ p \land q \Rightarrow p \land (q \lor r)\\[5pt]
\end{align*}$$

Clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a theorem like (a) in two ways, either to an antecedent or to a consequent.

(1) Assume you know that the sequent $p\lor q\Rightarrow X$ is valid. From (a) $p\Rightarrow p\lor q$ and cut/transitivity it follows that also $p\Rightarrow X$ is valid. You have *strenghtened* the antecedent from $p\lor q$ (the consequent of (a)) to $p$ (the antecedent of (a)). I guess this is what the authors mean with "transforming the consequent into the antecedent".

(On the other hand, the whole sequent $p\Rightarrow X$ is now *weaker* because it relies on a stronger premise!)

(2) Assume you know that the sequent $X\Rightarrow p$ is valid. From (a) $p\Rightarrow p\lor q$ and cut (transitivity) it follows that also $X\Rightarrow p\lor q$ is valid. You have *weakened* the antecedent from $p$ to $p\lor q$. In other words, you have transformed p (the antecedent of (a)) into $p\lor q$ (the consequent of (a)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's an interesting approach and it does make sense to me. However, I'm still puzzled as the book doesn't refer to a new term (which you call X). It seems that (a)-(e) all are derived from p => p, weakening/strengthening either or both sides of it. In the meantime I've found this post, please have a look at it: math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451892/understanding-and-using-strengthening-weakening-theorems The first answer interprets the formulas in themselves and not as parts of another expression. However, it still leaves the meaning of `transformation into` open.